# FamilyTree in HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to create a family tree in HTML.

Below is my code in html and css

```
<!--
We will create a family tree using just CSS(3)
The markup will be simple nested lists
-->
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="tree.css">
</head>
<div class="tree">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Krishna</a>
            <a href="#">Indu</a>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Sudarshan</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Anirudha</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
     </ul>
</div>
```

Below is my code in CSS

```
/*Now the CSS*/
* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}

.tree ul {
    padding-top: 20px; position: relative;

    transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

.tree li {
    float: left; text-align: center;
    list-style-type: none;
    position: relative;
    padding: 20px 5px 0 5px;

    transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;

}

/*We will use ::before and ::after to draw the connectors*/

.tree li::before, .tree li::after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute; top: 0; right: 50%;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 50%; height: 20px;
}
.tree li::after{
    right: auto; left: 50%;
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
}

/*We need to remove left-right connectors from elements without 
any siblings*/
.tree li:only-child::after, .tree li:only-child::before {
    display: none;
}

/*Remove space from the top of single children*/
.tree li:only-child{ padding-top: 0;}

/*Remove left connector from first child and 
right connector from last child*/
.tree li:first-child::before, .tree li:last-child::after{
    border: 0 none;
}
/*Adding back the vertical connector to the last nodes*/
.tree li:last-child::before{
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
}
.tree li:first-child::after{
    border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
}

/*Time to add downward connectors from parents*/
.tree ul ul::before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute; top: 0; left: 50%;
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 0; height: 20px;
}

.tree li a{
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #666;
    font-family: arial, verdana, tahoma;
    font-size: 11px;
    display: inline-block;

    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;

    transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

/*Time for some hover effects*/
/*We will apply the hover effect the the lineage of the element also*/
.tree li a:hover, .tree li a:hover+ul li a {
    background: #c8e4f8; color: #000; border: 1px solid #94a0b4;
}
/*Connector styles on hover*/
.tree li a:hover+ul li::after, 
.tree li a:hover+ul li::before, 
.tree li a:hover+ul::before, 
.tree li a:hover+ul ul::before{
    border-color:  #94a0b4;
}
```

Now issue is that I wish to create a connector between mother and father (Krishna) &(Indu). How do I do that?
Also the hovering effect doesnt work properly(when i select a tree element say Krishna) all its child's and child's child should get highlighted).

My output is this [image: output]

Now I wish to have connector between Krishna and Indu.Also the hovering effect on Indu is shown but on Krishna is not shown.

Comment: can you elaborate little about the connector..is it a big line connector or dot between and two lines passing to it

Comment: I have added ouput of my code for better visualization.Thanks

Comment: you could use the selector ~ instead > when sibling is not right behind. + can be used instead only-child : a little mixed of your code and my saying : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bdjMop (update from line 112)